# Iterar XML com VBA e repassar dados para as células

Tags: xml, microsoft-excel, vba, excel-vba

Estou começando a mexer agora com VBA e tenho o seguinte problema: consegui fazer um código que faz uma requisição SOAP para um webservice e me retorna um XML com os dados da marcação de ponto eletrônico de uma pessoa. Até aqui o código funciona tranquilamente.

O que estou com dificuldade é como passar os valores do XML para às células da planilha no Excel.

Exemplo de resposta do webservice: https://gist.github.com/rafinhacarneiro/084402c59a2f1a0e0e957baf7e6f27d9

Meu código:

```
linha = linhaResponse

For Each item In xmldoc.SelectNodes("//itens")
    coluna = colunaResponse

    Worksheets(response).Cells(linha, coluna) = item.SelectNode("//data")(0).Text

    For Each intervalo In item.SelectNodes("//intervalos")

        If intervalo.SelectNode("//dataHora").Text = "" Then
            coluna = coluna + 1: Worksheets(response).Cells(linha, coluna) = " "
        Else
            coluna = coluna + 1: Worksheets(response).Cells(linha, coluna) = intervalo.SelectNode("//dataHora").Text
        End If

        If Not (intervalo.SelectNode("//rep") Is Nothing) Then
            coluna = coluna + 1: Worksheets(response).Cells(linha, coluna) = " "
        Else
            coluna = coluna + 1: Worksheets(response).Cells(linha, coluna) = intervalo.SelectNode("//rep")(0).Text
        End If

        coluna = coluna + 1: Worksheets(response).Cells(linha, coluna) = intervalo.SelectNode("//tipo")(0).Text
        coluna = coluna + 1: Worksheets(response).Cells(linha, coluna) = intervalo.SelectNode("//justificativa")(0).Text
    Next intervalo

    coluna = coluna + 1: Worksheets(response).Cells(linha, coluna) = item.SelectNodes("//chp")(0).Text
    coluna = coluna + 1: Worksheets(response).Cells(linha, coluna) = item.SelectNodes("//ht")(0).Text
    coluna = coluna + 1: Worksheets(response).Cells(linha, coluna) = item.SelectNodes("//htr")(0).Text
    coluna = coluna + 1: Worksheets(response).Cells(linha, coluna) = item.SelectNodes("//htn")(0).Text
    coluna = coluna + 1: Worksheets(response).Cells(linha, coluna) = item.SelectNodes("//hnt")(0).Text
    coluna = coluna + 1: Worksheets(response).Cells(linha, coluna) = item.SelectNodes("//hi")(0).Text
    coluna = coluna + 1: Worksheets(response).Cells(linha, coluna) = item.SelectNodes("//faltas")(0).Text

    coluna = coluna + 1: Worksheets(response).Cells(linha, coluna) = item.SelectNodes("//banco")(0).Text
    coluna = coluna + 1: Worksheets(response).Cells(linha, coluna) = item.SelectNodes("//minutes")(0).Text
    coluna = coluna + 1: Worksheets(response).Cells(linha, coluna) = item.SelectNodes("//noturno")(0).Text
    coluna = coluna + 1: Worksheets(response).Cells(linha, coluna) = item.SelectNodes("//percentual")(0).Text


    coluna = coluna + 1: Worksheets(response).Cells(linha, coluna) = item.SelectNodes("//modo")(0).Text
    coluna = coluna + 1: Worksheets(response).Cells(linha, coluna) = item.SelectNodes("//valor")(0).Text


    coluna = coluna + 1: Worksheets(response).Cells(linha, coluna) = item.SelectNodes("//banco")(0).Text
    coluna = coluna + 1: Worksheets(response).Cells(linha, coluna) = item.SelectNodes("//bancoAuto")(0).Text

    linha = linha + 1
    i = i + 1

Next item

Set xmldoc = Nothing
```

O resultado disso é uma linha de resultados se repetindo várias vezes. O que deveria aparecer seria todos os dados de um `itens` (que seria um dia) em linha:

```
data                   dataHora               rep    tipo              justificativa    ...
2018-07-09T00:00:00Z | 2018-07-09T09:01:00Z |      | MarcacaoGeoMobi |                | ...
```

Comment: Amigo veja esse exemplo: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31420211/reading-xml-and-repeating-a-value-across-a-cell-range acho que pode te ajudar...

Comment: @Evis desculpe a demora, mas esse link ajudou bastante. Obrigado :)

Answer (score 0):

Bom dia,
Para esse seu caso, sugiro o uso do editor powerquery, pois você irá conseguir manipular o xml e converte em planilha mais facilmente.

att,

link para dowload do powerquery
https://support.microsoft.com/pt-br/office/iniciar-o-suplemento-power-pivot-para-o-excel-a891a66d-36e3-43fc-81e8-fc4798f39ea8